# Javascript- How do I change the background-image property in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-image

With Javascript, I am trying to change the background-image on my web app.

Here is how Im trying to do it:

```
const bgimg = {
   backgroundImage: "URL('../../Images/arches.JPG')"
    }
```

```
<div style={bgimg} id="bg_img">
```

This method works fine when I use a pic from the internet with it's url, but it wont let me add a local image. I can use the same pictures on my computer if I implement it right in css, like

```
.container_image {
  background-image: url(./Images/yellow_stone_copy.JPG)
}
```

But I want to be able to change the background, while it's running, to an image on my computer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you loading the html from? Those are all examples that give image path relative to the HTML file or css file.

Comment: can you share the project's file structure?

Comment: plus the `div` needs to to have the `container_image` class

Comment: You can't just randomly select an image on your computer. It has to be within the folder structure of your project; maybe in an `assets` folder.

Comment: So my HTML file is in the public folder, everything else is in src. From what I am now understanding, the images need to be in the public folder with the html? I thought this was an unusual practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the url of the image you want to use is relative to the html file and not to the js file

Comment: This worked!!! Thanks!! :) My html file is in the public folder, everything else is in src, so I was making the urls not relative to html. Ive been banging my head against the wall all day over this lol. Thanks again